# Check more than one array of zipcodes if exists then find corresponding rate

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm developing a theme in liquid (Shopify) and javascript. I've got three arrays of valid zipcodes that all have a corresponding shipping rate. This data comes from the Shopify theme sections settings.

Here's how this looks in the json output:

```
"zip-validator-rate-zone1": 10,
"zip-validator-zipcodes-zone1": "37201, 37203, 37204, 37220",

"zip-validator-rate-zone2": 15,
"zip-validator-zipcodes-zone2": "37205, 37206, 37207, 37208, 37209, 37210, 37211, 37212, 37214, 37215, 37216, 37217, 37218, 37219, 37221, 37064, 37067, 37069",

"zip-validator-rate-zone3": 20,
"zip-validator-zipcodes-zone3": "37027",
```

The user will input a zipcode and I need to check all three of these arrays to see if the zipcode is valid and then I need to get the corresponding rate that applies to that zipcode. I can't figure out how to do this elegantly without creating a bunch of variables.

Comment: How the array looks like??

Comment: That's a detail I should add. Not sure how best to create an array from json data.

Answer (score 0):

Since exact input array is not clear, I have made assumption that these 3 records exists as object in an array like below.

```js
let zoneArray = [{
    "zip-validator-rate-zone1": 10,
    "zip-validator-zipcodes-zone1": "37201, 37203, 37204, 37220",
  },

  {
    "zip-validator-rate-zone2": 15,
    "zip-validator-zipcodes-zone2": "37205, 37206, 37207, 37208, 37209, 37210, 37211, 37212, 37214, 37215, 37216, 37217, 37218, 37219, 37221, 37064, 37067, 37069",
  },
  {
    "zip-validator-rate-zone3": 20,
    "zip-validator-zipcodes-zone3": "37027"
  }
]

function getZoneRateByZipCode(code) {
  return zoneArray.map((d, i) => d['zip-validator-zipcodes-zone' + (i + 1)].split(', ').indexOf(code) > -1 ? d['zip-validator-rate-zone' + (i + 1)] : undefined).find(v => !!v)
}

console.log(getZoneRateByZipCode('37203'))
console.log(getZoneRateByZipCode('37069'))
console.log(getZoneRateByZipCode('37027'))
```